# iisnode on Windows 10 Pro - from Internal error 500.19 to Error code: 0x800F0954

Tags: asp.net, node.js, windows-10, iisnode, dism

I got a new PC at work with Windows 10 Pro and had to setup iisnode on it...

- I started by installing nodeJS (v8.11.3)
- got & installed iisnode-full-v0.2.21-x64
- got and installed urlrewrite2
- went to the iisnode installation folder to run setupsamples.bat file
- upon going to http://localhost/node/ and clicking any of the URLs, I got an 'Internal server error 500.19'

I realized that I had missed a [prerequisite](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode):'IIS 7.x with IIS Management Tools and ASP.NET'

To enable this features, tried the UI option: *Control Panel > Turn Windows features on or off > Internet Information Services > World Wide Web Services > Application Development Features*

Reading different posts, I tried enabling apparently everything other than 'CGI'. upon selecting each feature, I got the error in the snapshot below... Tried the resolution [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fcbb3e78-9427-4597-a7d6-7f87c9a118a1/cant-install-net-framework-35-errors-0x800f0954-and-0x800f081f?forum=win10itprosetup) but to no avail... DISM Logs had:

- DISM Package manager: CBS HRESULT=0x800f0954
- tried different combinations of fulfilling the ASP.NET pre-requisite through UI and command prompt but to no avail.

  [image: Errro code: 0x800F0954]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a while, I tried enabling the feature 'ASP.NET 4.7' only (some features were automatically selected by it)... this time it was smooth sailing through the UI.

http://localhost/node/ and its links worked like a charm

I documented the whole case here, hoping that it would help someone - Good luck !!